# Изменение sprite (наложение, вычитание) в runtime

Tags: c#, unity3d

Имеется объект содержащий Sprite Renderer со sprite-ом. (*холст*)

Имеется еще несколько sprite-ов. (*кисти*)

1. Как возможно реализовать **наложение** *кисточек* на *холст* с изменением самого *холста*?
2. Как реализовать **вычитание**?

Comment: Знаю что можно вносить изменения в текстуру. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.html   Но тогда измениться текстура навсегда(И это работало не очень быстро, когда я пробовал).  Можно использовать Trail Renderer И тогда получится типо рисование кистью.  А если надо сохранить, то можно сделать  скриншот вида из камеры

Comment: Сохранение не требуется, сейчас понял, что задача примерно аналогична созданию тумана войны, поищу еще

Comment: @Valera Kvip https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.html тут я так понял попиксельный доступ, верно? Вы упомянули, что пробовали, какой размер у текстур был и насколько медленно работало? У меня текстура 512 x 512 и только одна одновременно в runtim-е

Comment: Не помню, в рантайме рисовать не выйдет, будет медленно. Завтра посмотрю, может где код валяется(там нужно разобраться, потому что попиксельный доступ оооооочень медленный, но можно получить вроде сразу массив пикселей, завтра гляну).  Напиши конкретно какая задача, потому что если текстуру менять не надо, то это не то.

Comment: @Valera Kvip Упрощенно задача - во время игры открывать туман войны определенным образом (подготовленные формы) и закрывать тоже. Вроде бы нашел в каком направлении копать: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-RenderTexture.html

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение: отрисовка будет не SpriteRenderer-ом, а через Plane.

1. Создаем **RenderTexture**
2. Создаем камеру **Orthographic camera** (подстраиваем размеры под область холста)
3. Устанавливаем **RenderTexture** на камеру в **Target Texture** (изображение с камеры передается на эту текстуру)
4. Задаем камере **Clear Flags *Depth only*** (изображение не очищается, остается след от текстур попавших в камеру)
5. Выставляем камере **CullingMask** на 1 новый слой (например **mypaint**)

После этих манипуляций в поле зрения этой камеры, в слое **mypaint** можно создавать кисти и перемещать их, будет изменятся **RenderTexture**. Для отображения изменений необходимо создать новый материал и повешать на него эту текстуру. А сам **материал** на plane.

Это реализовано наложение. Вычитание реализуется изменением шейдера **материала**.

*вот тут подробно:* https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNAvNeOTnSE